# Unity FindWithTag returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, unity-game-engine

I have readed a lot of forums about this, and lots of answers, but I can not still solve this problem. When I have 1 door in my scene, everything is OK, but when I add another one, I am getting `NullReferenceException`.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour {
     public GameObject doorBody;
     GameObject useText;
     Transform player;
     private AudioSource doorSound;
     public float doorOpenAngle = 90.0f;
     public float doorCloseAngle = 0.0f;
     public float doorAnimSpeed = 2.0f;
     private Quaternion doorOpen = Quaternion.identity;
     private Quaternion doorClose = Quaternion.identity;
     private Transform playerTrans = null;
     public bool doorStatus = false; //false = close, true = open
     private bool doorGo = false; 
     void Start()
     {
         doorStatus = false; //door is open
         doorSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
         doorOpen = Quaternion.Euler(0, doorOpenAngle, 0);
         doorClose = Quaternion.Euler(0, doorCloseAngle, 0);
         playerTrans = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
         Debug.Log(playerTrans.position);
         useText = GameObject.FindWithTag("Use"); 
         useText.SetActive(false);
     }
     void Update()
     {
         if (Vector3.Distance(playerTrans.position, this.transform.position) < 2f)
         {
             useText.SetActive(true);
             if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !doorGo)
             {
                 doorBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
                 doorSound.mute = false;
                 if (doorStatus)
                 { //close door
                     StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorClose));
                     doorSound.Play();
                 }
                 else { //open door
                     StartCoroutine(this.moveDoor(doorOpen));
                     doorSound.Play();
                 }
             }
         } else
         {
             useText.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
     public IEnumerator moveDoor(Quaternion dest)
     {
         doorGo = true;
         while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.localRotation, dest) > 4.0f)
         {
             transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, dest, Time.deltaTime * doorAnimSpeed);
             yield return null;
         }
         //Change door status
         doorBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
         doorStatus = !doorStatus;
         doorGo = false;
         yield return null;
     }
 }
```

Exception:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Solution 'Shadow of Fear' ‎(3 projects)
>   Assets/Own/Scripts/Door.cs 49

[image]

Comment: Maybe because there is no object with tag 'Player', then `GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player")` returns null, which causes the error when you get the `transform`.

Comment: No, this is not a problem, there is an object with tag Player, and also unity says error on line 49 where is useText.setactive(true);

Comment: you used the doors tag lol.... I can tell you read a lot

Comment: @SethKitchen what are you talking about?

Comment: Seth means that **find** in game consume lots of resources of computer.

Comment: instead of useText = GameObject.FindWithTag("Use");       useText.SetActive(false); try this : Text t = GameObject.FindWithTag("Use").GetComponent<Text>(); t.active = false;